# Notifications on a new Route or with parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

easy simple question. 
I made a register form. When you press the submit button the Controller handles the request and renders.

```
if($form->isSubmitted && $form->isValid()) {
return $this->render('x/register.html.twig', array(
'options' => 'userCreated',
'userName' => $user->getUsername()); }
```

in the .html.twig

```
{% if options=="userCreated" %}
user {{userName}} was successfully inserted into the database

{% else %}
//show the form
```

`{% endif %}`

This worked perfect but my "teacher" told me, that I have to do this more dynamic.
I did a new "Info.html.twig" now with 2 parameters (redirectUrl, redirectText) e.g.

```
$redirectUrl="/home"; $redirectText="Go to the home page"
```

in HTML

```
<a href="{{redirectUrl}}">{{redirectText}}</a>
```

and if there is a message at the top I use the flashMessage method ($this->addFlash).

Is that a good method or is there a way to get way more dynamical than this?

Comment: imo i'm thinking your teacher was not very keen on the static check in your twig file. Resorting to the flash message bag is a better solution.

Comment: More related to DarkBee : http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages is a good starting point for adding Flash messages.

Comment: can I use the flash-messages for redirectUrl var aswell?

Comment: Yes, you can. The `addFlash` method will store your flash message in the session, so it can be collected/picked up by any view (or route/controller).